# django- to add ratings field

Tags: django-models

I just want to add an ratings filed. I've added djangoratings in installed apps and my model is

from django.db import models

from djangoratings import RatingField

class Rat(models.Model):

```
search= models.CharField(max_length=10)

rating = RatingField(range=5)
```

When I syncdb it comes up with no model found djangoratings. Is there anything i want to do more.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the package djangoratings? Following the install instructions [here](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings)

It seems like syncdb can't find the models.py of the djangorating package.